# A good that has been renamed to be sold at a higher price

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patagonian_toothfish):

The name "Chilean Seabass" was invented by a fish wholesaler named Lee Lantz in 1977. He was looking for a name that would make [the toothfish] attractive to the American market. He considered "Pacific sea bass" and "South American sea bass" before settling on "Chilean sea bass".[3] In 1994, the U.S. Food and Drug Administration (FDA) accepted "Chilean Seabass" as an "alternative market name" for Patagonian toothfish,[3] and in 2013 for Antarctic toothfish.

I imagine there is a word or phrase that isn't as formal as "alternative market name" for the process of taking an unappealing product, giving it a fancy name and jacking up the price, but nothing comes to mind.

Comment: “alternative market name” says nothing about the subsequent marketing ploy/tactic and jacking up the price.  Are asking about alternative phrases for “alternative market names” or are you asking about the tactic of renaming to a more sophisticated-sounding name in order to raise the price?

Answer (score 4):

The practice you are referring to is called  ***[rebranding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebranding)***:.

> - a marketing strategy in which a new name, term, symbol, design, or combination thereof is created for an established brand with the intention of developing a new, differentiated identity in the minds of consumers, investors, competitors, and other stakeholders.

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 3):

The good in question has been ***repackaged*** (presented in a new way, typically to make it more appealing).

M-W:

> **[repackage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repackage)**
>   *transitive verb*
>
> :  to package again or anew; specifically :  **to put into a more
>   efficient or attractive form**
>
> Large pieces of meat are cut and repackaged at the butcher's shop.

dictionary.com:

> **[repackage](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/repackage)**
>
> *verb* (used with object), repackaged, repackaging.
>
> **3.** to remake or alter so as to be more appealing or desirable:
>
> That politician's image needs to be repackaged.